# Test a component with useState and setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, settimeout, enzyme

Code structure is as same as given below:

**FunctionComponent.js**

```
...
const [open, handler] = useState(false);
setTimeout(() => {handler(true);}, 2000);
...
return (
...
<div className={active ? 'open' : 'close'}>
)
```

**comp.test.js**

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

test('test case 1', () => {
 expect(wrapper.find('open').length).toBe(0);
 jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
 expect(wrapper.find('open').length).toBe(1);
 jest.useRealTimers();
});
```

The problem is that the expression written in bold in test is saying the length of open class is still 0, so actual and expected are not meeting.

Comment: `.find(".open")`? It's a CSS selector.

Comment: I am using enzyme and jest

Comment: I know, you used those tags.

Comment: so i am trying to find the class using class selector, which we can do.
please refer below url:
https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/hasClass.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to test the outcome of the hook and not the hook itself since that would be like testing React. You effectively want a test where you check for if the open class exists and then doesn't exist (or vice versa), which it looks like you're trying.

In short, to solve your issue you need to use `".open"` when selecting the class. I would also suggest using the `.exists()` check on the class instead of `".length()"` and then you can use `".toBeTruthy()"` as well.

You could look into improve writing your tests in a [Jest/Enzyme combined](https://medium.com/codeclan/testing-react-with-jest-and-enzyme-20505fec4675) format as well:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { FunctionComponent } from './FunctionComponent.jsx';

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('<FunctionCompnent />', () => {
  const mockProps = { prop1: mockProp1, prop2: mockProp2, funcProp3: jest.fn() };
  const wrapper = shallow(<FunctionComponent {...mockProps} />);

  afterEach(() => {
   jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  it('should render as closed initially', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.close').exists()).toBeTruthy();
    // you could also add the check for falsy of open if you wanted
    // expect(wrapper.find('.open').exists()).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('should change to open after 2 seconds (or more)', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.open').exists()).toBeTruthy();
    // you could also add the check for falsy of close if you wanted
    // expect(wrapper.find('.close').exists()).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

EDIT: Sorry realised I wrote the test backwards after checking your code again, they should be fixed now.

Comment: i was using the .open only but someone edited my code. Btw i got the issue now. thanks for the shared url.

Comment: Ahh fair enough, curious that the edit was approved since it was incorrect but anyways. Happy you're on the way.